# How to build dynamic filter query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a working query with 2 parameters where multiple values can be searched.

```sql
Declare @age varchar(50) = '', @gender varchar(20) ='',@qry nvarchar(max)= ''
SET @qry = 'SELECT * FROM persons '
IF(@age <> '')
BEGIN
  SET @qry = @qry + ' WHERE age in ('+@age+') '
END
IF(@gender <> '' AND @age <> '')
BEGIN
    SET @qry = @qry + ' OR gender in ('+@gender+') '
END
IF(@gender <> '' AND @age = '')
BEGIN
    SET @qry = @qry + ' WHERE gender in ('+@gender+')'
END
```

But if I need to add new parameters in the future, I think the query might get too big. Is there a better approach to do this?

```sql
Declare @age varchar(50) = '', @gender varchar(20) ='',@qry nvarchar(max)= ''
SET @qry = 'SELECT * FROM persons WHERE 1=1 '
  + CASE WHEN @age IS NOT NULL THEN
    N' OR age in ('+@age+')' ELSE N'' END
  + CASE WHEN @gender IS NOT NULL THEN
    N' OR gender in ('+@gender+')' ELSE N'' END
```

Comment: [#BackToBasics: An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example). What you have there is a big injection issue too, I'm afraid. Especially when I doubt you *really* need 2,147,483,648 characters to store someone's age or gender?

Comment: @Larnu I have edited the variable declartions, I have tried to use the same approach as the link you provided before but I can't make it work. I think it only works when the query uses AND operator.

Comment: What you have is still an injection issue. If you've tried implementing the above, with parameterised dynamic causes, please do show use that attempt.

Comment: @Larnu Please see my edit. Also about the sql injection, The link said that it solves the injection issue. But I don't understand how, it still concatenates the parameters which I believe is the cause of an injection . Can you explain it to me?

Comment: It doesn't use `'...WHERE ID = ' + @ID` it uses `WHERE ID = @ID` and passes the value of the parameter `@ID` to the dynamic statement using `sp_executesql`.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, I understand now, however my main issue still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parentheses as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM persons
where  
   (age  in (@age) or @age='') and  
   (gender in (@gender) or @gender='') and 
   (OtherColumn in (@OtherParam) or @OtherParam='')
```

Comment: @age = '' will give me an empty result. What I wish to achieve is when the parameter is empty, age for example, all ages should be searched.

Comment: if the parameter is empty that means the first part will be omitted by the OR , therefore parentheses  scope is important

Comment: Sorry, I thought @age ='' is actually the column. Now I understand. Thanks.